# Decrease the size of every element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to decrease the size of all the #minimenu a links to its size /3
This code is to increase by 100px.

```
       $("#minimenu a").css({
            'width': '+=100',
            'height': '+=100'
        });
```

Is there anything for dividing the parent size /3? 
"/=3" is not working.

Comment: you could declare a variable that is equal to the element's width and then divide that variable by 3 and then set the width to that variable (same for height).

Comment: How I can scan all the elements and do the same thing to all of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to loop, each link could have a different size**

```
$('#minimenu a').each(function() {
    var e = $(this);
    e.width(e.width()/3);
    e.height(e.height()/3);
});
```

Comment: mine was right too but i just didn't give you full answer so you can try stuff on your own

Comment: Your answer jquery's the element twice and is half as performant.  It is also less concise and has formatting issues.

Answer (score 3):

If those links have the same size.

**jQuery**

```
        $("div").css({
            width: $(this).width() / 3,
            height: $(this).height() / 3
        });
```

Here is example
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w6vLf6w/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
var $minimenu = $("minimenu a"),
    height = $minimenu.height(),
    width  = $minimenu.width();

$minimenu.css({
                'width': height/3,
                'height': width/3
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
 $( "#minimenu a" ).each(function( ) {
          var controlHeight = $(this).height();
          var controlWidth = $(this).width();

          $(this).width(controlWidth/3);
          $(this).height(controlHeight/3);


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're shrinking them once only, you could simply do this:

```
$('#minimenu a').css('zoom', 1/3);
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#minimenu a').css('zoom', 1/3);
});
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Shrink</button>

<div id="minimenu">
  <a href="#">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  <a href="#">Dolor</a>
</div>
```